# Difficulty in computing the algorithm for collision detection (ball with paddle and bricks) in JavaScript breakout game

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Javascript breakout game but have an issue with detecting the collisions between the ball and both the paddle and bricks.

On running the program, I expect the ball to bounce off the paddle and the bricks if they collide. And if the ball collides with the bricks, the bricks would be removed.

I have tried executing the function checkForCollision(gw, paddle) within the animation code, setting that if the collider is the paddle, the ball will simply bounces off, and if not, it must be a brick. However, unfortunately, the ball simply passed through the colliders (paddle or bricks) and behaved as if the colliders did not exist.

Previously, I've tried several if/else variations to mend it, and have tried another method which specifies the bricks that were collided using its index position (e.g. [Not sure if this is constructed correctly] collidedBrick = bricks[i][j], where i and j is the number of rows and columns of bricks respectively). But the ball in the game still couldn't detect the existence of the colliders.

JavaScript code as follows:

```
const GWINDOW_WIDTH = 360;           
const GWINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;         
const N_ROWS = 10;                   
const N_COLS = 10;                  
const BRICK_ASPECT_RATIO = 4 / 1;   
const BRICK_TO_BALL_RATIO = 3 / 2;   
const BRICK_TO_PADDLE_RATIO = 2 / 3; 
const BRICK_SEP = 2;                 
const TOP_FRACTION = 0.1;          
const BOTTOM_FRACTION = 0.05;        
const N_BALLS = 3;                   
const TIME_STEP = 10;                
const INITIAL_Y_VELOCITY = 3.0;      
const MIN_X_VELOCITY = 1.0;         
const MAX_X_VELOCITY = 3.0;          


const BRICK_WIDTH = (GWINDOW_WIDTH - (N_COLS + 1) * BRICK_SEP) / N_COLS;
const BRICK_HEIGHT = BRICK_WIDTH / BRICK_ASPECT_RATIO;
const PADDLE_WIDTH = BRICK_WIDTH / BRICK_TO_PADDLE_RATIO;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = BRICK_HEIGHT / BRICK_TO_PADDLE_RATIO;
const PADDLE_Y = (1 - BOTTOM_FRACTION) * GWINDOW_HEIGHT - PADDLE_HEIGHT;
const BALL_SIZE = BRICK_WIDTH / BRICK_TO_BALL_RATIO;

/* Main program */

function Breakout() {
  let gw = GWindow(GWINDOW_WIDTH, GWINDOW_HEIGHT);
  let bricks = createBricks(gw);
  let paddle = createPaddle(gw);
  let ball = createBall(gw);
}


function createBricks(gw) {
  let x0 = (gw.getWidth() - (N_COLS * BRICK_WIDTH) - (N_COLS - 1) * BRICK_SEP)/2;
  let y0 = TOP_FRACTION * gw.getHeight();
  let color = ["Red", "Orange", "Green", "Cyan", "Blue"];

  for (let i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N_COLS; j++) {
      let x = x0 + j * (BRICK_WIDTH + BRICK_SEP);
      let y = y0 + i * (BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP);
      let bricks = GRect(x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
      bricks.setFilled(true);
      bricks.setColor("White");
      bricks.setFillColor(color[Math.floor(i/2)]);
      gw.add(bricks);
    }
  }
}


function createPaddle(gw) {
  let x0 = (gw.getWidth() - PADDLE_WIDTH) / 2;
  let y0 = PADDLE_Y;
  let paddle = GRect(x0, y0, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
  paddle.setFilled(true);
  gw.add(paddle);

  let mouseMoveAction = function(e) {
    let x = e.getX() - (PADDLE_WIDTH / 2);
    let y = PADDLE_Y;
    if (x > 0 && x <= gw.getWidth() - PADDLE_WIDTH) {
      paddle.setLocation(x, y);
    }
  };
  gw.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveAction);
}


function createBall(gw) {
  let centerX = gw.getWidth() / 2;
  let centerY = gw.getHeight() / 2;
  let x0 = centerX - (BALL_SIZE / 2);
  let y0 = centerY - (BALL_SIZE / 2);
  let ball = GOval(x0, y0, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
  ball.setFilled(true);
  gw.add(ball);

  let clickAction = function(e) {
    let vy = INITIAL_Y_VELOCITY;
    let vx = randomReal(MIN_X_VELOCITY, MAX_X_VELOCITY);
    if (randomChance()) vx = -vx;

    let step = function() {

      if (ball.getX() > 0 && ball.getY() > 0 &&
          ball.getX() < gw.getWidth() - BALL_SIZE &&
          ball.getY() < gw.getHeight() - BALL_SIZE) {
        ball.move(vx, vy);
        let collision = checkForCollision(gw, paddle);
      }

      if (ball.getX() < 0 || ball.getX() > gw.getWidth() - BALL_SIZE) {
        vx = -vx;
        ball.move(vx, vy);
      }
      if (ball.getY() < 0) {
        vy = -vy;
        ball.move(vx, vy);
      }
      if (ball.getY() > gw.getHeight()) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    };
    let timer = setInterval(step, TIME_STEP);
  };
  gw.addEventListener("click", clickAction);
}

function checkForCollision(gw, paddle) {
  let collider = getCollidingObject(gw, ball);

  if (collider !== null) {
    if (collider !== paddle) {
      vy = -vy;
      ball.move(vx, vy);
      gw.remove(collider);
    }
    else {
      vy = -vy;
      ball.move(vx, vy);
    }
}

function getCollidingObject(gw, ball) {
  let x = ball.getX();
  let y = ball.getY();
  let object = null;

  object = gw.getElementAt(x, y);
  if (object !== null) {
    return object;
  }
  object = gw.getElementAt(x, y + BALL_SIZE);
  if (object !== null) {
    return object;
  }
  object = gw.getElementAt(x + BALL_SIZE, y);
  if (object !== null) {
    return object;
  }
  object = gw.getElementAt(x + BALL_SIZE, y + BALL_SIZE);
  if (object !== null) {
    return object;
  }
}
```

Below is the html file which directs to JavaScript Graphics library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Breakout</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='https://cs106ax.stanford.edu/jslib/JSGraphics.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='https://cs106ax.stanford.edu/jslib/RandomLib.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='Breakout.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body onload='Breakout()'></body>
</html>
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add reproducible code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added it. @AhedKabalan

Comment: Still I can't test the output since this code using Java graphics library. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added a HTML file which directs to Javascript graphics library. I hope that helps. Thanks. @AhedKabalan